# R warning: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, vector, warnings, mle

I am running the following code and getting the warning "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length."

I want to create a function that stores the vector l with different values based on 3 criteria (r>1e-6, r<-1e-6, and 1e-6>r>-1e-6).  The values are going to be based on the parameters of the function and will then be maximized using the nlm command.

```
ll <- function(param, r, rm) {
  a1 <- param[1]
  a2 <- param[2]
  b <- param[3]
  sigma <- param[4]
  nr <- length(r)
  l <- vector("numeric",nr)
  for (j in 1:nr) {
    l[j] <- ifelse(r>1e-6, log(1/(2*pi*sigma^2)^(1/2)) - ((1/2)*sigma^2)*(r+a2-b*rm)^2,
            ifelse(r<-1e-6, log(1/(2*pi*sigma^2)^(1/2)) - ((1/2)*sigma^2)*(r+a1-b*rm)^2,
                   log(pnorm((a2-b*rm)/sigma) - pnorm((a1-b*rm)/sigma))))
  }
  return(-sum(l))
}
```

Comment: should use `r[j]` instead of just r in the loop

Comment: @rawr Adding the [j] to r and rm in the loop cleared that warning but I am now receiving the error "NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value." Any ideas?

Comment: not really. how are you calling `ll`? and you should be using more whitespace, eg, there is a huge difference between `r <- 1e-6` and `r < -1e-6`

Comment: `out <- nlm(ll, p=c(-.03,.03,.1,.01), r=datasettest[["returns"]], rm=datasettest[["euroreturn"]])`
returns the error
`NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value` 

and

`out1 <- optim(c(-.03,.03,.1,.01), ll, r=datasettest[["returns"]], rm=datasettest[["euroreturn"]])` 
returns the error
`function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters`